# Allocate elastic ip addressto spot instance using aws CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

By using AWS CLI,
would like to assign fixed elastic ip address to my Spot request configuration,
launched with AWS CLI.

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/request-spot-instances.html
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do it. You need to get the instance ID of the spot instance once it is running and the `allocation-id` of your Elastic IP.

Let us say you have the instance ID in a variable called `$instanceId` in a bash script.

When you have an Elastic IP address, you can go into AWS interface and copy the `allocation-id` for that Elastic IP address.

With this `allocation-id` and the `instance-id` of your spot instance, you can write the following command in your script or the command line (adjust accordingly to your region):

```
aws ec2 associate-address --allocation-id "eipalloc-d0drandomizedac1792" --instance-id $instanceId --allow-reassociation --region eu-central-1
```

We normally do this with a bash script, for example for one "demo system" that we launch automatically at some points. This way everybody in the team knows the IP of this server, even when it is an spot instance.